# Override primeng css classes in Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, overriding, primeng

The thing is that I want to override the CSS classes of primeng and change some colors. No matter how I do it it doesn't change. If change the ViewEncapsulation to none the component doesn't even appear. I've tried something like this:

```
.ui-chkbox-box.ui-state-active, .ui-radiobutton-box.ui-state-active {
 border: 1px solid red !important;
  background: red !important;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Trying to override the properties in the component css but it still doesn't work.

I know other people have asked the same question but none of the answers has helped me so I'm a little bit desperate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add ::ng-deep

```
::ng-deep .ui-chkbox-box.ui-state-active{...}
```

Comment: Its not working in my case. I am using Angular 16 and PrimeNG 16.

Comment: @Shrip The answer is 'very' old for an old version. I guess they changed the class name. Open dev tools on browser and inspect the element to get the classname. If you have a quick demo, give the url, I could try to help

Answer (score 0):

I added the classes to the app.less file and it worked like a charm. The component `.css` was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to override the PrimeNG CSS.

```
:host ::ng-deep .ui-chkbox-box.ui-state-active {
   // your css code
}
```

Its is working in version 16.x.x