# Style backgroundColor p-fileUpload primeNG

Tags: angular, primeng

I work with a application angular 4 and p-fileUpload component.

I want to change the background-color of component and the color of label text.

I try to change the style in a css file but it doesn't work

```
.ui-button.ui-fileupload-choose.ui-widget.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.ui-button-text-icon-left{
 background-color: #3F51B5 !important;
    border: 3px solid #3F51B5 !important;
    color: #d30e0e !important;
}
```

However the generated code in html is:

```
<span class="ui-button ui-fileupload-choose ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon-left" ng-reflect-klass="ui-button ui-fileupload-choose" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
            <span class="ui-button-icon-left fa fa-plus" ng-reflect-klass="ui-button-icon-left fa" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]"></span>
```

What the problem ?
Is it possible ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Better to add HTML markup along with your css code.

Comment: span.ui-button doesn't work

Comment: checkout this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280708/override-primeng-css-classes-in-angular/46280815#46280815

Comment: ok good ... ng-deep ... I have forgotten  thanks a lot

Comment: Also, this one, although you are not using for AM, it's the same solutions :) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46770809/5468463

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider adding the CSS you want to overwrite in the global `styles.css` file located in the root of your project instead of the component CSS file.

Comment: it works. But isn't it against the Angular's componentization principle?